Seaborn plot no default rainbow color - only showing blue
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
sns.catplot(data = penguins, x='island', kind='count')

plt.show()


As you can see I only have blue bars. I've tried sns.reset_orig() and setting other Matplotlib color palettes. Nothing seem to give me more than one color.
I have Seaborn version : 0.13.2 and Matplotlib version : 3.7.1, I am also on a MacBook.
Please help... how do I get the default rainbow color?

Seaborn uses the hue parameter to group together elements via color.  If you want a color per island, you can use sns.catplot(data=penguins, x='island', kind='count', hue='island').  In older seaborn versions you might need sns.catplot(..., dodge=False) to prevent Seaborn creating space for multiple bars per x value. To get a rainbow coloring where each color has similar darkness, you can use sns.catplot(..., palette='turbo')

Seaborn's default behavior for categorical plots is to use a single color. To use rainbow-like color or colors of your choice you could use the hue parameter.
So in this line, you could do something like:
sns.catplot(data = penguins, x='island', kind='count', hue='island', palette='rainbow')

This will generate a different color for each category bar. You could also change the palette parameter to suit your liking. Hope this helps.
